# How many languages are there in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, languages

How many languages are there in *Star Wars* canon and is there any list of their names and maybe examples?

P. S. Droid language counts too.

Comment: C-3PO is fluent in "over three million forms of communication" so my guess would significantly over three million.

Comment: In the words of the Bombad Warrior Jar Jar Binks: [_muy muy_](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Languages)

Comment: 6 million plus, at least

Comment: And we see Threepio doesn't know all the forms of communication in RotJ, where he has some trouble understanding Ewoks at first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Tim's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/189704/58193) is accurate prior to *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* but from then on the actual answer is:

## Over 7 million; no accurate canon answer available

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens - The Visual Dictionary* it shows us that C-3PO has upgraded his TranLang III communications package to learn more languages, over seven million to be "precise".

> [image: Star Wars: The Force Awakens - The Visual Dictionary, C-3PO's Data File]
>
> C-3PO has upgraded his TranLang III communications package to increase his language fluency to over seven million forms of communication.

Comment: He's got a holy big hard drive.

Comment: Oh, is that really C3PO? I almost didn't recognise him because of the arm.

Answer (score 10):

## Over 6 million; no accurate canon answer available

As C-3PO [states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8OI-NVMVa8) to EV-9D9 in *Return of the Jedi*:

> "I am fluent in over six million forms of communication, and can readily..."

This does not cover all forms. In *Return of the Jedi*, we [see C-3PO having trouble communicating with Ewoks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdSqrtKQ37E) (they speak a very primitive dialect):

> LUKE: Do you understand anything they're saying?
>
> THREEPIO: Oh, yes, Master Luke! Remember that I am fluent in over six million forms of communication.
>
> HAN: What are you telling them?
>
> THREEPIO: Hello, I think... I could be mistaken. They're using a very primitive dialect. But I do believe they think I am some sort of god.

Also, droids evolve all the time, and even if a droid or individual knows all droid languages at one point in time, at a later point new forms may appear.

So we have a lower estimate of **6 million**, which is known to be an underestimation.

Answer (score 6):

If we go by Legends Canon and Wookieepedia there were around 560 languages defined to some degree:

```
▪   Aargauese
▪   Abednedish
▪   Abyssin language
▪   Adarese
▪   Advb
▪   Agarian language
▪   Ahak Maharr language
▪   Aleena language
▪   Alliance Special Forces hand signals
▪   Altirish
▪   Amanese
▪   Anarrese
▪   Ancient Askajian
▪   Ancient Corellian
▪   Anointed People's language
▪   Anomid sign language
▪   Anselmian
▪   Ansionian language
▪   Antarian
▪   Anx language
▪   Anzat language
▪   Aqualish language
▪   Arconese
▪   Argazdan language
▪   Arkanian language
▪   Askajian language
▪   Atoan language
▪   Ayrou language
▪   B'rknaa language
▪   Bab-Neo
▪   Bab-Prime
▪   Balc
▪   Balinaka language
▪   Balosur
▪   Barabel language
▪   Baragwinian
▪   Batorese
▪   Besalisk language
▪   Bimmini
▪   Bith language
▪   Bocce
▪   Bogolanese
▪   Boordist
▪   Bosph language
▪   Bothese
▪   Brrbrlpp language
▪   Bunduki language
▪   Caamasi language
▪   Caarimala
▪   Calian language
▪   Caluulan
▪   Caridan language
▪   Carioglyph
▪   Carosite language
▪   Catharese
▪   Cerean language
▪   Chadra-Fan language
▪   Chagri
▪   Chandrilan language
▪   Charon language
▪   Cheunh
▪   Chev language
▪   Chevin language
▪   Chistori language
▪   Chubbini
▪   Chuhkyvi language
▪   Classical Ossan
▪   Clawdite language
▪   Cloddogran language
▪   Codruese
▪   Colicoid language
▪   Concordian
▪   Coruscant Charm Signing
▪   Coway (language)
▪   Coynite language
▪   Cragii
▪   Critokian language
▪   Croke language
▪   Crucible language
▪   Cuvacian language
▪   Dai Bendu language
▪   Daimli
▪   Dakoti
▪   Dantarian
▪   Dashadi
▪   Dat-an
▪   Dathomiri language
▪   Dathomirian language
▪   Deception sect dialect
▪   Defel language
▪   Delphanian language
▪   Delphidian common tongue
▪   Devaronese
▪   Dianoga language
▪   Diollan language
▪   Dosh
▪   Drabatese
▪   Dradan language
▪   Draethos language
▪   Drallish
▪   Dressellese
▪   Dromnyr
▪   Drovian language
▪   Dug language
▪   Duinuogwuin language
▪   Durese
▪   Ebranese
▪   Ebruchese
▪   Eickarie language
▪   Electrospeech
▪   Elom (language)
▪   Elomin language
▪   Em'liy language
▪   Emperor's Royal Guard battle language
▪   Epicant
▪   Ergesh language
▪   Esh-kha language
▪   Ettian
▪   Evocii language
▪   Ewok trade language
▪   Ewok-Basic pidgin
▪   Ewokese
▪   Falleen language
▪   Farghul language
▪   Feeorin language
▪   Felucianese
▪   Ferroan language
▪   Fftssfft language
▪   Fian language
▪   Filordian
▪   Firrerreo language
▪   Flames of the Crucible
▪   Fosh language
▪   Frigosian language
▪   Frizznothese
▪   Frozian language
▪   Frusoise
▪   Fuzzum language
▪   Gacerian language
▪   Gados language
▪   Galactic Basic
▪   Galactic Basic Standard
▪   Galactic Sign Language
▪   Gamorrese
▪   Gand language
▪   Geelan language
▪   Gen'Dai language
▪   Geonosian language
▪   Geonosian hive-mind
▪   Gerbese
▪   Gigoran language
▪   Givin language
▪   Gobindi language
▪   Gorothite language
▪   Gossam language
▪   Gree language
▪   Gungan Basic
▪   Gunganese
▪   Gutretee language
▪   Guudrian language
▪   H'kig language
▪   H'nemthe language
▪   Hakaran language
▪   Hamadryas language
▪   Hand signals
▪   Hapan language
▪   Herglese
▪   High Coruscanti
▪   High Galactic
▪   High Sith
▪   Ho'Din language
▪   Honoghran
▪   Horansi language
▪   Houkese
▪   Hrakian language
▪   Hras'kkk'rarr
▪   Hsoosh
▪   Huhk language
▪   Huralok language
▪   Huttese
▪   Iktotchese
▪   Illodian language
▪   Illodian Sibilant
▪   Imperial Basic
▪   Iscerian language
▪   Ishi Tibrin
▪   Iskalonian language
▪   Issori language
▪   Ithorese
▪   Ixll language
▪   Iyra language
▪   Janguine language
▪   Jarellian
▪   Jastaal language
▪   Jawaese
▪   Jeh
▪   Jenet language
▪   Jessaran
▪   Kabalian
▪   Kadri'Ra language
▪   Kage language
▪   Kalaanite language
▪   Kalai language
▪   Kaleesh language
▪   Kaminoan language
▪   Kedorzhan language
▪   Kel Dor language
▪   Kerestese
▪   Kerkoidese
▪   Keshiri language
▪   Khilese
▪   Khomm language
▪   Kian'thar language
▪   Killik language
▪   Kilmaulsi language
▪   Kindalo language
▪   Kinetic communication
▪   Kitonese
▪   Klatooinian language
▪   Kobothi
▪   Koorivar language
▪   Korunnal
▪   Krantian Language
▪   Kreva
▪   Krish language
▪   Kruskan language
▪   Kuat language
▪   Kubazian
▪   Kumumgah language
▪   Kurtzen language
▪   Kushiban language
▪   Kyhhhsik
▪   Kyuzo language
▪   Lanai's language
▪   Langhesan
▪   Lannik (anguage
▪   Lasat language
▪   Lepese
▪   Lok Pirate's Cant
▪   Lorellian language
▪   Lowickese
▪   Lugubraal
▪   Lupre'en
▪   Lurmese
▪   Lutrillian language
▪   Mairan language
▪   Malagarrian language
▪   Mandaba
▪   Mando'a
▪   Maser voice-stream
▪   Massan
▪   Massassi language
▪   Meerian (language)
▪   Melodese
▪   Menahu
▪   Menahuu
▪   Mid-Galactic Standard
▪   Middle Yutanese
▪   Military Sign
▪   Mimbanite language
▪   Miralukese
▪   Mirialan language
▪   Mistryl battle language
▪   Mon Calamari blink code
▪   Mon Calamarian
▪   Morish language
▪   Morodin language
▪   Morpitoo's language
▪   Morseerian language
▪   Mugaar language
▪   Murachau
▪   Mustafarian language
▪   Muun language
▪   Muza language
▪   Myke language
▪   Myneyrsh language
▪   N'or
▪   Naboo language
▪   Nagaian
▪   Nalros language
▪   Nanilas
▪   Nautila
▪   Nazren language
▪   Nazzar language
▪   Necropolitan language
▪   Neimoidian language
▪   Nelvaanese
▪   Neti language
▪   Nikto language
▪   Nimbanese language
▪   Noehonese
▪   Nosaurian language
▪   Notho
▪   Notron Cant
▪   Nuffese
▪   Nuknog language
▪   Nyriaanan (language
▪   O'reenian language
▪   Oblee language
▪   Old Corellian
▪   Old Coruscanti
▪   Old Drall
▪   Old Galactic Standard
▪   Old Gungan
▪   Old High Gamorrese
▪   Old High Squibbian
▪   Old High Trammic
▪   Old Tarmidian
▪   Old tongue
▪   Old X'Tingian
▪   Oldspeak Basic
▪   Olys Corellisi
▪   Omwatese
▪   Ortolan language
▪   Ovoni language
▪   Paecian
▪   Paigun language
▪   Pak Pak
▪   Pamarthen language
▪   Pantoran language
▪   Parwan language
▪   Peh
▪   Phindian language
▪   Pho Ph'eahese
▪   Pirates of Tarnoonga language
▪   Pitrillistian language
▪   Plattahr's species language
▪   Pre-Corellian
▪   Priap
▪   Prison dialect of Kessel
▪   Proto-Huttese
▪   Psadan language
▪   Pugali
▪   Pydyrian language
▪   Pyn'gani language
▪   Q2800
▪   Qella language
▪   Qieg language
▪   Qiiluran
▪   Quarrenese
▪   Quermian language
▪   Quesoth Common Speak
▪   Quesoth Soldier Speak
▪   Qwohog language
▪   Qwohog sign language
▪   Rakata language
▪   Ramoan language
▪   Ranat language)
▪   Ranth language
▪   Rattataki language
▪   Rhommamoolian language
▪   Riileb language
▪   Riorian language
▪   Rodese
▪   Rodian language
▪   Royal Script of Grizmallt
▪   Rozzum language
▪   Ru language
▪   Ruurese
▪   Rybese
▪   Ryn language
▪   S'kytric
▪   Saheelindeeli language
▪   Sakiyan language
▪   Samuac Tree Code
▪   Sanyassan language
▪   Sarkese
▪   Sasha ot Sulem's dialect
▪   Sauvax language
▪   Savrip language
▪   Sedri language
▪   Selkath language
▪   Semaphore
▪   Semblan
▪   Seoulian
▪   Shadda-bi
▪   Sharu Trammic
▪   Shashay language
▪   Shem-Lern's species language
▪   Shi'idese
▪   Shimiese
▪   Shistavanen language
▪   Shusugaunt language
▪   Shyriiwook
▪   Sign language
▪   Sith language
▪   Sith tongue
▪   Skakoform
▪   Skakoverbal
▪   Skandit language
▪   Skel language
▪   Skrilling language
▪   Slithese
▪   Sljee language
▪   Sluissese
▪   Sluudrese
▪   Smuggler cant
▪   Snee
▪   Snivvian language
▪   Socorran language
▪   Spaart
▪   Squalris language
▪   Squibbian
▪   Sriluurian
▪   Ssi-ruuvi
▪   Stereb language
▪   Sullustese
▪   Surmo-Clarithian
▪   Svivreni language
▪   Swoken
▪   Sy Bisti
▪   Symbian
▪   T'landa Til language
▪   T'surrese
▪   Tahlboorean language
▪   Taloron language
▪   Talz language
▪   Talzzi
▪   Tap code
▪   Tapani language
▪   Tarasin Skintone Language
▪   Tarasinese
▪   Tarc language
▪   Tarrese
▪   Tchuukthese
▪   Teedospeak
▪   Teek language
▪   Teevo
▪   Teh
▪   Temolish
▪   Thakwaese
▪   Thisspiasian language
▪   Thobek language
▪   Thykarann
▪   Thyrsian language
▪   Tibranese
▪   Tionese language
▪   Tiss'shar language
▪   Tof language
▪   Tognath language
▪   Togorian language
▪   Togruti
▪   Torrock
▪   Toydarian language
▪   Tra'ang'a
▪   Trader's argot
▪   Tranese
▪   Trianii language
▪   Trinary
▪   Tritonite language
▪   Troig language
▪   Troxan language
▪   Tsi
▪   Tundan
▪   Tunrothese
▪   Turazza language
▪   Tusken
▪   Tusken/Legends
▪   Twi'leki
▪   Tynnan language
▪   Ubeninal
▪   Ubese language
▪   Ugnaught language
▪   Ugor language
▪   Umbarese
▪   Une
▪   Unidentified Kobothi S-Corps "code" languages
▪   Unidentified language (Zzzzyxxx)
▪   Utai language
▪   Utapese
▪   Utapese/Legends
▪   Uthuthma language
▪   Uukaablian language
▪   Vaathkree trade language
▪   Vagaari language
▪   Vahla language
▪   Valltii language
▪   Vashan language
▪   Verpine language
▪   Vodran language
▪   Vodran language
▪   Vortexlex
▪   Vorzydiak language
▪   Voss language
▪   Vratix language
▪   Vregg
▪   VT-7
▪   Vulpterish
▪   Vuvrian language
▪   Wartaky
▪   Wasilsi language
▪   Wehttam language
▪   Whiforla-song
▪   Whiphid language
▪   Wistie language
▪   Wol Cabasshite language
▪   Woostese
▪   Worxi
▪   Wroonian language
▪   X'Tingian
▪   Xaczik
▪   Xamster language
▪   Xan language
▪   Xextese
▪   Xi Char language
▪   Yahk-Tosh language
▪   Yakan
▪   Yarin language
▪   Yarkora language
▪   Yashuvhi language
▪   Yeb language
▪   Yevethan language
▪   Yinchorri language
▪   Yrashu language
▪   Ysannan
▪   Yuuzhan Vong language
▪   Yuzz
▪   Yuzzum language
▪   Zabraki
▪   ZeHethbra language
▪   Zelosian language
▪   Zeltron language
▪   Zimchai
▪   Zolanese
▪   Zygerrian language
```

I don't really know that much about Disney Canon so I can't really give you an answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

**68.**

We all know that Threepio is fluent in millions of forms of communication (even though binary load lifters and moisture vaporators are very similar in most respects) but only 68 languages are shown in the canon movies according to the [StarWarsKids YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDe7m0POuwkL1gwnQ-FVhMw) in a video seemingly made for this question.  The video [Every Language in Star Wars Movies | Star Wars By the Numbers - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZp8Civk2co) has a list and examples of every language being spoken. They also included droid languages.

Here is the list from the end of the video:

Gunganese,
Astromech Binary,
Sisrai,
Clawdite,
FettCode,
Gossam,
Skakoverbal,
Geonosian,
Colicoid,
Shyriiwook,
Imroosian,
Cynogan,
Azumel,
Danzikan,
Olys Corellisi,
Croci,
Daldom,
Pyke,
Death Trooper Encryption,
Brabatese,
Iakari,
Jawaese,
Kyhhhsik,
Gonkian,
Tusken,
Nyahnyah,
Arconese,
Talzzi,
H’Nemthe,
Antarian,
Sarkese,
Chadra-Fan,
Saurin,
Durese,
Lamproid,
Shimiese,
Ithorian,
Aqualish,
Huttese,
Kubazi,
Cruly-3,
Omnisignal Unicode,
Dosh,
Ughanese,
Gammorrean,
Rybese,
Borish,
Ubese,
Ewokese,
Sullustese,
Hideo,
Teedospeak,
Uthuthma,
Jablogian,
Dowutinese,
Ubdurian,
Culisetto,
Compressed Umbilic Unicode,
Jawren,
Delphidian,
Abednedish,
Lanai,
Taarja,
Bufopel,
Khamarese,
Cloddogran,
Cantonican,
Basic

**TLDR:** There are over 7 million forms of communication in the galaxy but only 68, including droid languages, are shown in the cannon live action movies.

Comment: I think you need to include canon shows like *The Mandalorian* and the *Clone Wars* series, but this is not a bad start.  It would be better if you identified the speakers and scene for each though.

Comment: @DavidW - Agreed. Star Wars "canon" is far more than just the films. There's TV shows, cartoons (CGI and drawn), comics, etc

Comment: Yes I think TheLethalCarrott and TimSparrows answers are correct but when I saw that video I was amazed at how well it answered the question.  I guess I could have just made an extra long comment.

Comment: it's a good answer @L.T.Smash - just not fully comprehensive of the entire canon :)