# What's in-universe name of Hindi in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

There are [over 7 million languages in Star Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/205227/931) and in-universe name of English is Galactic Basic. If you watch the following video (in original undubbed version), Hindi also exists in the galaxy far far away:

(The background song is in Hindi in case you don't understand Hindi)

What's the in-universe name of it?

Comment: Do you know what planet they're on in that video, or the species of the musicians? It might help identify an origin, if there is one.

Comment: Hindi seems to have some influence. Padme is a variation of Padma meaning Lakshmi, a Hindu Goddess.

Comment: @Kozaky - It's a Weequay bar (owned and operated by Weequay pirates). You hear other hindi-inspired songs when you visit another Weequay-owned bar later in the series.

Comment: Hindi (or any other earth language) may not have existed yet.

Comment: @Kozaky It's Hondo's fortress on Florrum.

Comment: @S S  You are wrong.  English is not named Galactic Basic in Star Wars.  Instead the Galactic Basic language is translated into the Earth language English by Earth human filmmakers making Star Wars movies and shows on the planet Earth, and Earth human actors without major makeup are chosen to portray the most important species in the Star Wars galaxy. So there is no Hindi language in the Star Wars galaxy, instead the Earth language Hindi is used to translate one of the many languages in the Star Wars galaxy..

Comment: @M.A.Golding Haha.. Yeah, that's one way to view it.

Comment: Which canon work is this video from?

Comment: @Spencer *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series..

Comment: Although I agree but original song is Mera Dildar Bada Sona by Alka Yagnik, Sonu Nigam, Sukhwinder Singh, Jaspinder Narula https://youtu.be/ltiVnd5dJCI

Comment: @M.A.Golding From all sources I can find, this is incorrect. I don't know of any evidence that most of Star Wars is "translated." I've only seen that claimed for works like the Ewoks cartoon.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dooku_Captured#Behind_the_scenes), the song was indeed Hindi.

> The song played in the background in the pirate stronghold is a Hindi
>   song known as "Indian Pop Source", composed by the series' composer
>   Kevin Kiner.

Since Hondo Ohnaka's gang was a group of only Weequays (despite of a couple of Kowakian monkey-lizards) and the performance took place at their complex, I think it's safe to say Hindi acted out as **Sriluurian**, the native language of Weequays. Although there were some Jawas and Bith (who were well-known musicians) at the stronghold, and the performers was never shown in the episode, it's still presumable the song was sung in the audience's native tongue.