# Are there any other real life languages in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, languages

As [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205229/whats-in-universe-name-of-hindi-in-star-wars) established, the Hindi language does actually exist in the Star Wars universe, likely as the Sriluurian language. Of course there is also the fact that almost everyone speaks Basic, which is equivalent to English. So my question is, are then any other examples of a real life language being spoken/used in Star Wars, or is it just basic and the occasional Hindi?

Legends and canon are both acceptable.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Language/Legends

Comment: Feel free to copy/paste and self-answer

Comment: Assuming that Earth languages heard spoken by Star Wars characters were the actual words they said is just as dubious as assuming that they look like they do in the movies and episodes. Star Wars allegedly happened "long ago in a galaxy far, far away" and somehow information about those events has been acquired by modern Earth filmmakers - and nobody knows how accurately the films reproduce the "historic" events they are about.  Probably no better than most movies about historic events on Earth.